# How do you co-ordinate concurrent related requests to optimize performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, concurrency

I have a scenario where related images are requested in parallel from the client.  These images need to be dynamically generated on demand based on the json results from a search.

The following diagram outlines the flow.  Requests A, B and C are all based on the same search parameters but return images related to result items 0, 1 and 2 respectively.  The idea is that the requests are likely to come in nearly simultaneously at T0. The first request should execute the search and persist the results.  After the results are persisted, all the requests can continue generating a different image based on the data.

[image: Co-Ordinating Concurrent Image Generation Requests]

The question is, what is the right pattern for handling these requests, co-ordinating the search job and then allowing the subsequent image gen jobs to run and return?  There's no way to control the requests or have them poll.

Comment: Is there a way for you to put the requests in a queue?  This would let you pipeline them